# Вывод таблицы с чередованием трёх цветов строки

Tags: php, sql, foreach

Таблица представляет собой характеристики товара. Есть заголовок группы характеристик и сами характеристики. Необходимо вывести массив настроек в виде таблицы [таким образом](https://yadi.sk/i/gcfVZOx6qWVYr) Причём, чтобы чередование цвета всегда начиналась с одного цвета. Вариант с чётными и нечётными знаю, как сделать:

```
foreach($specs_item_full AS $key => $value){
  $i++;
  if($i $i%2 == 0){
    echo "<tr style='background-color: #eeeeee'>
                <td class='spec_title'>
                    $key
                </td>
                <td class='spec_details'>
                    $value
                </td>
            </tr>
            ";
  } else {
    echo "<tr style='background-color: #e2e2e2'>
                <td class='spec_title'>
                    $key
                </td>
                <td class='spec_details'>
                    $value
                </td>
            </tr>
            ";
  }
}
```

Но как вывести заголовок пока не пойму. Причём в варианте, который указан выше, чередование начинается не с одного цвета - если в массиве чётное количество элементов, то начинает с одного цвета, если нечётное - с другого. Если бы заканчивал разными цветами, то ясно, а тут - не понятно. Ключ массива - название характеристики на кириллице, значение - само значение характеристики. Заголовок идёт с пустым значением.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно запомнить значение текущего раздела, в отдельной переменной, например $key_curr. Сравнивать на каждой итерации это значение с предыдущим значением, если они совпадают - выводить характеристики чередуя.

```
<?php
$key_curr = null;
$i = 0;
foreach($specs_item_full AS $key => $value){

  if($key == $key_curr) {
    $i++;

    if($i % 2) $color = "#eeeeee";
    else $color = "#e2e2e2";

    echo "<tr style='background-color: {$color}'>
                <td class='spec_title'>
                    $key
                </td>
                <td class='spec_details'>
                    $value
                </td>
            </tr>
            ";
  } else {
    $key_curr = $key;
    echo "<tr style='background-color: #ffffff'>
                <td class='spec_title' colspan='2'>
                    $key
                </td>
            </tr>
            ";
  }

}
```

Если вам в следующем разделе вам нужно продолжить чередование предыдущего - просто используйте предыдущие значение счетчика $i, если нужно начать чередование цветов с какого-то начального цвета, обнуляйте значение $i в else-блоке (выше приводится первый вариант).

Comment: cheops спасибо. Только я не совсем понял. Получается, будет чередоваться просто 3 цвета, то есть три строки вывел, потом заново три строки. Или я не так понял? Мне нужно, чтобы в цикле шла проверка по значению ключа, например, если получает false, то выводит цвет заголовка, а остальные строки чередуются двумя цветами. Характеристик может быть сколько угодно. На фото у меня для примера после заголовка 4 строки.

Comment: Возможно, мой вариант вывода характеристик крайне неудобен, но я ничего более удобного не смог придумать...

Comment: Поправил ответ, не сразу понял, что требуется.

Comment: cheops спасибо большое, только $value на null проверяем. Сделал без `$key_curr = null;` написал `if($value != null){...}else{...}` Вроде, работает

Comment: Ещё решил обнулять `$i` после каждого заголовка `...else{$i=0 ...}`, чтобы чередование заново начиналось и так красивее)